# Display the number of lower case letters in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what I have so far:

```
count=0
mystring=input("enter")
for ch in mystring:
    if mystring.lower():
        count+=1
print(count)
```

I figured out how to make a program that displays the number of lower case letters in a string, but it requires that I list each letter individually: `if ch=='a' or ch=='b' or ch=='c'`, etc. I am trying to figure out how to use a command to do so.

Comment: What stops you `print`ing each `ch`?

Comment: nothing really, other than that its too time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.  Instead of:

```
if my.string.lower():
```

It should be:

```
if ch.islower():
```

If you have any questions ask below.  Good luck!

Comment: `ch.lower()` will always be `True`, because `ch.lower()` is the lowercase version of `ch`, and nonempty strings test as `True`. I think the OP needs `if ch.islower():` instead.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of the '.islower' method.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like homework! Anway, this is a fun way of doing it:

```
#the operator module contains functions that can be used like
#their operator counter parts. The eq function works like the
#'=' operator; it takes two arguments and test them for equality.
from operator import eq
#I want to give a warning about the input function. In python2
#the equivalent function is called raw_input. python2's input
#function is very different, and in this case would require you
#to add quotes around strings. I mention this in case you have
#been manually adding quotes if you are testing in both 2 and 3.
mystring = input('enter')
#So what this line below does is a little different in python 2 vs 3,
#but comes to the same result in each.
#First, map is a function that takes a function as its first argument,
#and applies that to each element of the rest of the arguments, which
#are all sequences. Since eq is a function of two arguments, you can
#use map to apply it to the corresponding elements in two sequences.
#in python2, map returns a list of the elements. In python3, map
#returns a map object, which uses a 'lazy' evaluation of the function
#you give on the sequence elements. This means that the function isn't
#actually used until each item of the result is needed. The 'sum' function
#takes a sequence of values and adds them up. The results of eq are all
#True or False, which are really just special names for 1 and 0 respectively.
#Adding them up is the same as adding up a sequence of 1s and 0s.
#so, map is using eq to check each element of two strings (i.e. each letter)
#for equality. mystring.lower() is a copy of mystring with all the letters
#lowercase. sum adds up all the Trues to get the answer you want.
sum(map(eq, mystring, mystring.lower()))
```

or the one-liner:

```
#What I am doing here is using a generator expression.
#I think reading it is the best way to understand what is happening.
#For every letter in the input string, check if it is lower, and pass
#that result to sum. sum sees this like any other sequence, but this sequence
#is also 'lazy,' each element is generated as you need it, and it isn't
#stored anywhere. The results are just given to sum.
sum(c.islower() for c in input('enter: '))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will handle UTF or special characters very nicely but should work for at least ASCII in Python3, using the `islower()` function.

```
count=0
mystring=input("enter:")
for ch in mystring:
    if ch.islower():
        count+=1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct version of your code would be:

```
count=0
mystring=input("enter")
for ch in mystring:
    if ch.islower():
        count += 1
print(count)
```

The method `lower` converts a string/char to lowercase. Here you want to know if it IS lowercase (you want a boolean), so you need `islower`.

**Tip:** With a bit of wizardry you can even write this:

```
mystring= input("enter")
count = sum(map(lambda x: x.islower(),  mystring))
```

or

```
count = sum([x.islower() for x in mystring])
```

(`True` is automatically converted to `1` and `False` to `0`)

:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use following method:

```
mystring=input("enter:")
[char.lower() for char in mystring].count( True ) )
```